# Create txt file with jQuery - preserve line breaks

Tags: php, jquery, text-files

I use jQuery to serve a link where users can download a .txt file. jQuery just gets the content of a textarea and sets it as the href attribute. This is necessary because the content of the textarea is set with the response of an ajax call.

The download of the file works like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#download', function(){
  $(this).attr('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent( $('#kundendaten').val() ) );
});
```

One part of the Ajax call response is the textarea:

```
$kundendaten = '<textarea id="kundendaten">';
   $kundendaten .= 'Name: '. $_POST['nachname'] .' '. $_POST['vorname'] . PHP_EOL;
   $kundendaten .= 'Email: '. $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL;
$kundendaten .= '</textarea>';
```

On Mac OS I get a .txt file with line breaks and everything is fine. On Windows though the line breaks are missing in the .txt file. I also tried `\n` instead of `PHP_EOL` but there was no difference.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: can you try to use `"\r\n"` for your linebreaks instead of `PHP_EOL` ? Remember to put them in double quotes

Comment: On windows you'll need `\r\n` - unless you open the file in a text editor that supports DOS formatted line breaks. So it's both a matter of the OS and the editor.

Comment: The `PHP_EOL` constant holds the line break sequence _on the server side_. That obviously has nothing to do with the client sides sequence.

Comment: @DasSaffe no, unfortunately, this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

PHP_EOL only works to the system it is running on, so if your website is hosted on a linux box, it will do the EOL to a linux standard.

The following would be your best bet.

```
$kundendaten = '<textarea id="kundendaten">' . "\r\n";
   $kundendaten .= 'Name: '. $_POST['nachname'] .' '. $_POST['vorname'] . "\r\n";
   $kundendaten .= 'Email: '. $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$kundendaten .= '</textarea>' . "\r\n";
```

Also if you are using this a lot throughout a file I would create a constant referencing "\r\n" and use that. (If I remember the syntax correctly, as follows;

```
DEFINE("_EOL", "\r\n");
```

Comment: I tried this, but as I wrote in the comment above, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @oliverspies If you are using notepad, try to open it in notepad++, wordpad or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, yes, in Wordpad it's shown correctly (but not the special characters). Even though the "show line breaks" option is active in Notepad. So I just changed .txt to .rtf - all users should open the file in another editor now. Thanks